# Wordpress 4.4 release produce blank white images when sharing a post on Facebook etc

Tags: posts, facebook

After upgrading to 4.4, when I share a post via URL to Facebook, G+, the "Featured Image" shows as a blank white image on the Facebook post. Looks fine on the Wordpress site.

Some testing shows that Wordpress sends the full resolution photo to Facebook, so maybe it's too large for Facebook?

I suspect something changes in the way Wordpress shares images with the new Responsive image feature in 4.4x .

Here's my facebook home, look for the post labelled "Test Post" about Mac & Cheese.

https://www.facebook.com/gordwait

Comment: Hi, this is a little vague an no real question is asked. If you have proven it's being sent please show where. Additionally list the size of the photo.

Comment: Ok, the implied question is how do I fix it. Someone on the Wordpress forum loaded the URL into the Facebook debugger and found that it worked in that context, and that the original unscaled image was being sent (26 megapixel). This perhaps is being rejected by Facebook. Never had this issue before 4.4 installed.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook's URL Debugger (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) finds the image just fine and I am able to share with the image. It could be that the image was somehow not there or not accessible when you first tried to share the URL. I would try to share it again and see if it works now.

FYI, if you run into issues in the future, use the debug tool linked above and after retrieving the URL click "Fetch new scrape information". This can clear the Facebook cached info for your URL. This can be very useful if you add or change an image after the post has been shared the first time.

Comment: I'll try the Facebook debugger again. Someone else tried that for me, and found that the image was the full size 26 megapixel file I originally uploaded.  Wordpress used to instantly generate a handful of various resolutions when I uploaded a file. I also scaled down this image and edited the post to use the new image, but it still fails for me. The original large size has been there for a day or so, so it wasn't because I didn't wait long enough.